# I have an array of numbers and i wanna add it to an input autofill list on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

// on Html side
<Input type="text" id"users" />

// JavaScript
Var i = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll want to make an attempt and  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please may you make sure that the question includes a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be assuming what your problem is, since there is no related code.

Below code will take your input on clicking the button and then add the no. to the list using a javascript function

**your HTML file**

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var ListOfNumbers=[]
  function addButton(){
  var a=document.getElementById("users").value;
  ListOfNumbers.push(a);
  }
 </script>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="users">
  <button onclick="addButton()">Add to list</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want maybe this can help you !
first create nilai-asal.php for the original value to make it easier to retrieve the value if the value comes from the database.
enter the following code of nilai-asal.php :

```
    <?php
    // if value come from database just enabled this.
    //require_once('connection.php');
    //        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
    //        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    
    //        $date = time_elapsed_string($row['date']);
    //        $data[] = array(
    //            'num' => $row['num'],
    //            );
    //    }
    
    
    //    echo json_encode(array("result" => $data));
    $a = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
    
    foreach($a as $b){
        $c[] = array(
            'num' => $b
        );
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $c));
```

then create a utama.php file to display the value of nilai-asal.php
enter the following code of utama.php :

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div id="main"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                update();

    });

    function update() {
        $.getJSON("hasil.php", function(data) {
        $("#main").empty();
        var no = 1;
        $.each(data.result, function() {
            var num = this['num'];
        
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.value = num; //THIS IS VALUE OF INPUT
            input.id = num; //THIS IS ID OF INPUT 
        $("#main").append(input);
        });
    
        });
    }
    </script>
```